# How to make Eclipse expand all code when a file is opened?

Tags: eclipse

When I open a file, all code is collapsed into a single line. This is very annoying. How do I make Eclipse expand all code when a file is opened?

I read about the keyboard shortcuts but I simply want it to always expand all code automatically. I had this feature before but something went wrong I guess :/

Comment: If what you probably want is to maximize the Editor View. `Ctrl+M` should do that.

Comment: I don't want to maximize the window I want the code to be displayed fully expanded when I double click a file in the project explorer. Right now its all collapsed to a single line. Very annoying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> folding -> initially fold these elements -> uncheck all the elements
```